# Inserting multiple links to one image in Confluence

Tags: confluence

I am setting up a Wiki in Confluence v3.5.1
I have added a visio diagram (JPG) to a page (this diagram will take up most of the page)
- This diagram depicts the workflow between developers and support and clients.

I envisage users being able to click on different parts of the diagram and it to open up child pages with more details about that particular process (with videos on 'how-to' do that specific task, like log issues in Jira)

However, from what I can see, there is no way from the Confluence editor to add multiple links to the one image, right?  I looked at [Anchors](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Working+with+Anchors#WorkingwithAnchors-Examples), but this does not look like it will do the job.

So, what is the best option?

[image]

I remember Dreamweaver having these sorts of tools built in, and there appears to be other [utilities](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/30/how-to-create-multiple-links-on-a-single-image-with-image-map/) that can help put in [image map HTML tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp), but I cannot see a way of easily editing the HTML in Confluence editor.  Also worried about the headache this could cause with managing future changes of the page.

Comment: I was really hoping you had an answer for me on this one. I'm dreaming of the exact same thing. The Gliffy guys have mentioned a new HTML5 editor is in the pipeline and that it COULD be a feature of that release.... but I WANT IT NOW If anyone has any ideas or knows of anything out there, please scream out

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the following plugin allows you to work with image maps.
I'm about to test it, not sure if it works with your version of Jira.

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/de.dl.confluence.plugin.imagemap.ImageMapPlugin

Comment: I've since been using the Gliffy plugin to achieve a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

Split the diagram into tiles (separate images), so that each clickable region is a separate tile (and the remaining tiles fill in the gaps). Then put all the tiles on the same page. You'll have to experiment to see if Confluence puts them together how you want. Hopefully they will wrap at the right place so that all the images looks like the original. Then put links around the clickable regions - http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Linking+an+Image.